# File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg. \include{Chapters/Chapter5}

Tags: errors, captions

```
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,psfrag}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % suppress hyphenation *globally*
\sloppy 
\newcommand{\HY}{\hyphenpenalty=25\exhyphenpenalty=25} 
% re-enable hyphenation locally inside "Z" columns
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\HY\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X} 

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography} % The filename of the bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\captionsetup{
    justification = centering
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}


\begin{document}    
\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter5} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter6} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter7} 

\end{document}
```

I got this error on defining chapter5:

```
File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg. \include{Chapters/Chapter5}
```

I'm really new in latex and i don't know hot to fix it. It seems that part of chapter 5 is displayed and the other part not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a `{` without a matching `}` in a `\caption` somewhere (possibly in chapter 4)  but impossible to say where. Please try to make a complete small example that shows the problem.

Comment: unrelated but do not use `epsfig` package.

Comment: If you find yourself in such a situation, the problem is exactly what David said. Start looking in the document where some { or } is lacking. Quite exhausting, but that's exactly the solution. You probably pressed a button while typing your text and didn't realize it. That's a common situation while typing in laptops.